# How to use join() in yii2 ActiveDataProvider

Tags: yii, yii2

```
public function actionIndex(){
    $activeData = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Student::find()->joinWith('jurusan')->all(),
        'pagination' => [
            'defaultPageSize' => 12,
        ]
    ]);
    return $activeData;
}

public function getStudentJurusan()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Jurusan::className(), ['jurusan_id' => 'student_jurusan_id']);
}
```

I have Student and Jurusan which in realted, Student hasOne Jurusan and student jurusa_id is jurusan jurusan_id.
I want to get the student * except the student jurusan_id and the jurusan_name in jurusan without the jurusan_id.

Answer (score 0):

Relation name in 'query' is wrong.

It should be:

```
'query' => Student::find()->joinWith(['studentJurusan']),
```

Comment: The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses.

Comment: And i think i made a mistake it should be join()?? not joinWith because i what i want is full join. not left join.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the specifics columns, you should use query builder provided by Yii2.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html

hope this answer your question.